# What is the difference between io.sort.factor and min.num.spills.for.combine in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

we are doing some performance testing on our 20 node cluster. So tweaking some of the values.. where I came across these two properties..
io.sort.factor  and min.num.spills.for.combine.

In fact I am a bit confused on which will affect the merging of spilled files from buffer memory..

Comment: Can u update what are the factors in combination with this. Like Split size, block size.

Comment: blocksize is 64mb.. I didn't change min & max split size.. so split size will  be the same.